# unable to get/set content from tinymce textArea

Tags: angular, tinymce

In Angular4 I m generating textAreas dynamically ngFor and im initializing tinymce using element Selector "textarea" now I'm unable to get/set the content with controlid which I have assigned to textarea.

> ex: tinymce.get("textArea_1").getContent(); // Im unable to get/set
>   the content of textArea_1

When I m trying with following code textbox and its content is identified with some random id's like "mce_30, mce_31...." but i have given the control id's as "txtArea_0, txtArea_1..."

```
for (inst in tinyMCE.editors) {    
  if (tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent)    
   alert("inst: "+inst+" "+tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent());
}
```

can someone help me to resolve this issue?